# How does the logic for finding leap years work?

Tags: c++, logic

The programme was about finding the leap year but I couldn't understand the logic:

```
if(year%4==0 and not year%100==0 or year%4==0 and year%100==0 and year%400==0)
```

Please help me to understand the logic (I know how the `!`, `||` and `&&` operators work).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please note that C and C++ are two very different languages. Please pick *one* language.

Comment: Okay,I will read.

Comment: Are you trying to understand why that detects a [leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)?

Comment: Yeah.Trying to understand how this is detecting leap year.

Comment: Do you know how the leap years are determined (in real life)? And do you know what the `%` operator does?

Comment: Yeah,I know how to determine leap year(in real life)and what % operator does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That piece of code is trying to understand if the year you've provided is a *leap year* or not. A year is a leap year if:

- it is divisible by 4, hence `year%4==0` **and not** by 100, hence `year%4==0 and year%100==0 and year%100==0`

OR if:

- it is divisible by 4 **and** by 100 **and** by 400, hence `year%400==0`

The whole expression would be more readable if you add a couple of brackets:

```
if( (year%4==0 and not year%100==0) or (year%4==0 and year%100==0 and year%400==0) )
```

**note**: the whole expression might be simplified. Since a number divisible by 400 is also divisible by 4 and 100, you can write:

```
if( (year%4==0 and not year%100==0) or year%400==0 )
```

Comment: Sure. First of all, do you know what the modulo `%` opeator mean?

Comment: Yes,I know what it does mean.

Comment: ok. Consider the last statement I wrote. It is equivalent to yours but easier and shorter. So, notice that inside the if block there are 2 terms connected with a `or`. Let's evaluate the one inside the brackets. At the left of the `and` you are asking for the year being divisible by 4, while on the right of the `and` you want the year not to be divisible by 100. If this condition holds, there's no need to evaluate the other on the left of the `or`. If it doesn't, then you want year to be divisible by 400. If either the first or the second condition holds, you have a leap year, else not.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm to determine if a year is a leap year is as follows:

- Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except for years that are exactly divisible by 100, but these centurial years are leap years, if they are exactly divisible by 400.

---

For example, the years 1700, 1800, and 1900 were not leap years, but the years 1600 and 2000 were.